# Why isn't my sprite moving in pygame when I press the keys?

Tags: python, pygame

I have an issue where I can render my sprite on the background, but then when I use arrow keys, nothing is happening.

```
#sidescrolling air-shooter
import pygame
#import pygame locals
from pygame.locals import(
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

#constants for screen width/height
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Player, self).__init__()
            self.surf = pygame.Surface((75,25))
            self.surf.fill((255, 255,255))
            self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()

           #Moves sprite based on keypresses
        def update(self, pressed_keys):
            if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
            if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
            if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
            if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

pygame.init()
#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# Instantiate player
player = Player()
#keep the game running!
running = True

#loop time!
while running:
    #look at all the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #did the user hit a key?
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Was it escape?  uh oh we gotta stop
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        elif event.type ==QUIT:
            running = False

    #gets the keys that were just pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #updates location based on keys
    player.update(pressed_keys)
    #fill screen with white
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    # Create a surface and pass in a tuple containing legth and width
    surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))

    # Give the surface a color to separate it from the Background
    surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
    rect = surf.get_rect()

    #This line says "Draw surf onto the screen at the center"
    screen.blit(surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
    #Draw the player on the screen
    screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm really struggling to understand where I've done wrong here.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to draw the *Sprite* on the location stored in the `rect` attribute:

<s>`screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

[`pygame.Surface.get_rect.get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) returns a rectangle with the size of the *Surface* object, but it returns a rectangle that always starts at (0, 0) since a *Surface* object has no position.
The Surface is placed at a position when it is `blit` to the display.

You've to set the location of the rectangle, either by a keyword argument, e.g:

```py
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Player, self).__init__()
            self.surf = pygame.Surface((75,25))
            self.surf.fill((255, 255,255))
 
           self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

        # [...]
```

Use a [`pygame.sprite.Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group). [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update) and [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw) are methods which are provided by `pygame.sprite.Group`.
The former delegates the to the `update` method of the contained [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`s](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) - you have to implement the method.

> [`pygame.sprite.Group.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.update)
>
> Calls the update() method on all Sprites in the Group.

The later uses the `image` and `rect` attributes of the contained `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s to draw the objects - you have to ensure that the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`s have the required attributes

> [`pygame.sprite.Group.draw()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group.draw)
>
> Draws the contained Sprites to the Surface argument. This uses the Sprite.image attribute for the source surface, and Sprite.rect for the position.

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Player, self).__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface((75,25))
            self.image.fill((255, 255,255))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
```

```py
player = Player()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

while running:
    # [...]

    #gets the keys that were just pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #updates location based on keys
    all_sprites.update(pressed_keys)

    # Give the surface a color to separate it from the Background
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

Complete example:

```py
import pygame
#import pygame locals
from pygame.locals import(
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)

#constants for screen width/height
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self):
            super(Player, self).__init__()
            self.image = pygame.Surface((75,25))
            self.image.fill((255, 255,255))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

           #Moves sprite based on keypresses
        def update(self, pressed_keys):
            if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
            if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
            if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(-5,0)
            if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
                self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

pygame.init()
#create screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

# Instantiate player
player = Player()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites.add(player)

#keep the game running!
running = True

#loop time!
while running:
    #look at all the events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #did the user hit a key?
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            #Was it escape?  uh oh we gotta stop
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        elif event.type ==QUIT:
            running = False

    #gets the keys that were just pressed
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    #updates location based on keys
    all_sprites.update(pressed_keys)

    # Give the surface a color to separate it from the Background
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Your example works when I copy paste it, but I don't understand why mine doesn't if I edit it to look like yours.  The only thing I manage to accomplish is to remove the sprite entirely.  Why take out the first screen.blit function?

Comment: @sbrevolution5 You constantly blit the Sprite in the center of the window `screen.blit(player.surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))`. You ignore `player.rect` completely. Furthermore the color of your sprite is white and the background of your window is white, too.